# Plus or minus equals on jQuery element does not work. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run:

```
console.log($('.' + menu_id)[0].className);
```

I get:

```
main-mobile-menu hide-left
```

When I run:

```
console.log($('.' + menu_id)[0].className -= ' hide-left');
```

I get:

```
NaN
```

I can set the class using:

```
$('.' + menu_id)[0].className = 'main-mobile-menu'
```

but I don't understand why -= is not working.  I know there is a removeClass method in jQuery, but I've been trying to use native javascript with jQuery elements when possible.

Comment: Why do you want to use "native javascript with jQuery elements"?

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, why don't you make use of the .addClass() and .removeClass() functionality?

Comment: The `-` operator is *only* for numbers, not for strings.  `+` on the other hand has **two** functions.  It's *both* addition and string concatenation.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I want to use native JS for speed purposes.  Recently read [this](http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-or-native-method-everyday-techniques-no-3) article which measures the speed differences of mixing native JS with jQuery elements.  Not significant in a small app, but can add up over months/years of coding.

Comment: @ltrainpr: Then why are you *mixing* jQuery and "vanilla JS"?  Use one or the other, don't mix-and-match.  Why waste time with jQuery in the first place if you are just going to ignore it and use native DOM methods?  Calling the jQuery constructor is a waste of time if you're not gonna use jQuery methods.  See also: http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: @RocketHazmat You make a very good point.  Is there any reason to use jQuery over native JS?  Thank you for the Vanilla JS info.

Comment: @ltrainpr: jQuery has its advantages, yes.  There is a tradeoff however.  And that tradeoff is speed.  jQuery is designed to work around cross-browser issues.  With jQuery, you don't need to worry about whether or not you are using the correct API for IE/Chrome/Firefox/whatever.  It takes care of that for you.  It also may be easier to write jQuery code than vanilla JS code, but that's a personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` can be used for string concatenation but once you add a string to a number the entire variable becomes a string, so `-=` can't be used because subtracting a string from a string isn't possible.

If you want to only use javascript I would suggest using [`.replace("old","new")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

*Example:*

```
console.log($('.' + menu_id)[0].className.replace("hide-left", ""));
```

Comment: Ok that was fast.  Thank you for providing a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

because `-` doesn't do that. It does numeric subtraction. The `className` isn't a number and `'main-mobile-menu'` isn't a number, and the result is not-a-number.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript/Jquery `+` is used for concatinating string, but `-` can be used for arthmetic operations on int but not on string.

Comment: In *JavaScript*, you mean.  jQuery isn't a language.